# Tablesorter reload tbody or only that row on database change/update

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, tablesorter

I have seen a lot of examples of [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com) triggering an update when the user want's to add or remove a row in a table but I would like to see if it's possible for it to reload the entire row or tbody if there is a change in the database ?

This is what I was thinking to do so please let me know if this is a good idea or not.

**THE SETUP in JAVASCRIPT and PHP:**

**1.** When the page first loads the script will go and get a (.PHP) page that will display the lastUpdate (eg: '2013-07-18 10:37:29') the .PHP page will going to the database (MySQL) and get the lastUpdate and display it) this lastUpdate info (date/time) will be saved in a VAR to use later.

**2.** Add a timer that will ping that same (.PHP) page and compare it's lastUpdate vs the initial lastUpdate that we got when the page first loaded.

**3.** We will keep pinging every x amount of seconds (maybe 10 sec) to sniff for changes to the lastUpdate in the database.

**4.** (Compare): If the initial lastUpdate value is less then the one we just got from the database then this would mean that the content of the database has been changed and it would do one of the two possible things.

**What I would love to do from this point is:**

***Option 1:*** Only remove the old row and replace it with the updated one. 
Every row has a unique ID so javascript can also get this ID# and then just update that row in the table.

OR

***Option 2:*** Delete the Current Tbody and then Reload the entire Tbody with the new data.

The table has a lot of rows/colums and uses images,hrefs, and so on... so each row is a heavy row and that is why I would like to use Option 1 if possible, ***but I don't know how to get do this last part!?***

(unlike a chat program) The rows don't have to be in the right order, as long as I know what ID's where updated in the database.

Let's say that we have a address book that users can edit/update, add, remove contacts and contact info., now what I just want is to scan for changes and when a change is found send the ID and data of that row from the database to the row in the table matching it up via the ID and then update it or delete the old one and replace it with the new one, but if the id is not found in the database then remove the id from the table since it's no longer in the database.

so the only problem I can run into would be that more then one user made changes at the same time (like at the exact sec.) and then only one update would show. but I think this would be possible to bypass by checking with the database if there are any other different ID's with the exact date/time and if there is then update them also.

Thank you so MUCH for reading this and with any help you provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebSockets and/or server push.
If you have 1000 clients, that would be 0.1*1000=100 requests per second.
I am not sure your server side will be okay with that.

When using websockets or server push, on the event of database updating (someone who updates it should throw an event), the server sends to clients:

- the order of database rows (they all have unique IDs)
- the rows that has changed

It is better to use something different from PHP to update clients. Java Servlets, for example. Maybe, only for the task of updating the db rows on client side, I mean, you can keep the initial PHP page.

Answering to @compcobalt:
Simplifying, u receive two data types via websockets.

- JSONencoded array
- XML document containing the table rows

Here is the array: `[47,27,1001,36,4,833,5,98,478,...]`. The array contains **ALL** the IDs of the database rows **in the right order**. The right order may be, e. g., the order of the rows in the database. The javascript now immediatly modifies the html table to correspond to that order. Even if before there were row#26 and now there is no such row in the array, javascript deletes it.

```
<tr data-id="47">...</tr><tr data-id="27">...</tr><tr data-id="1001">...</tr>
```

Even if the JS does not know anything about row#1001 or if the row#27 has been updated.
Then, it takes the XML document (or JSON too, or any format you like) and parses it.

Here it gets the content of updated row#27 and the new row#1001 and fills the table rows with the content.

Then, starts waiting of the new server push.

Comment: aerm, unique ID means that even if in ["a","b","c"] the #1 element is deleted: ["a","c"] and a new element "d" is pushed_between(0,1): ["a","d","c"], the indexOf("d") element will be #3, not #1. Thus, the id does not represent the order, just the unique identificator.

Comment: okay, if the DB updater does not throw the event, make the database inform you (by "you" I mean the servlet).

Comment: @compcobalt depending on your server.

Comment: @compcobalt that is not the nature of AJAX. It's nature is **to get info from the server when the client wants**, **NOT THE SERVER**.

Comment: @comcobalt E. g. you have 1K of users. When you use the AJAX/timer tactic, you have 100Hz of permanent load. When you use server push, you have 1'000Hz of immediate load, for exact one second. I mean, then you may put your web app on a shared hosting...

Comment: (unlike a chat program) The rows don't have to be in the right order, as long as I know what ID's where updated in the database. 

Let's say that we have a address book that users can edit/update, add, remove contacts and contact info., now what I just want is to scan for changes and when a change is found send the ID and data of that row from the database to the row in the table matching it up via the ID and then update it or delete the old one and replace it with the new one, but if the id is not found in the database then remove the id from the table since it's no longer in the database.

Comment: so the only problem I can run into would be that more then one user made changes at the same time (like at the exact sec.) and then only one update would show. but I think this would be possible to bypass by checking with the database if there are any other different ID's with the exact date/time and if there is then update them also.

Comment: @compcobalt maintaining database data -- deleting/merging duplicates, removing bad items etc. is a completely different task and it should be discussed with a lot more concrete context or even specific customer requirements. If the order of the rows in table is not important at all, then just blow on it and check if there is all the rows with specified in first json array IDs in tbody and there is no rows with IDs that are not specified in the array (create/delete em). And fill it with the data.

Comment: @compcobalt then, of course, there is nothing wrong to use sorting plugins, *because you are just quantitatively improove usability, aka, adding features*.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1. Less data sent back and forth. Less rendering.

That's what I would do:

Have a `JS` setTimeout function with `AJAX` checking my server side script/servlet/whatever. If any row matches the `SQL` query, I'd send them back through `JSON`.

With my JSON back, I'd parse every `JSON` object (table row), and replace the respective `TR` with the new data.

Comment: Yup, but I don't know how to get past this part, I cannot even make option 2 work; I have been trying to trigger $("#tablesorter-demo").trigger("update"); on every change but it doesn't seem to work, it looks as if it reloaded the entire tbody but doesn't display the changes.

Comment: @compcobalt maybe you go a level or two down? For example, code the the the whole JS thing by your hands? jQuery is in the right place here, sure, but instead of making some bs plugins work, you may do something more interesting. And the whole JS will be faster ;)

Comment: @compcobalt I mean, if you you will receive the ID order from the server, there is nothing so hard to code table updating by yourself. First, insert new TRs and sort existing, second, update them.

Comment: @user1990577 just to make sure that I understand: I get the ID back from the database that has changed, and then how do I locate the existing ID in the table and replace it or update it with the new one data ?

Comment: @aldux Thanks for the suggestion: That's what I would love to do also, but it look's like a super hard and time consuming task without any plugin(s) that was/where already created for something like this, right ? What do you think ? (I also updated some stuff at the bottom of my question to clear up a couple of things and make people understand alil better what I'm trying to do)

Comment: @compcobalt No. I think you will (I did) lose more time understanding someone's API than just code what you want. I can see no super hard task, just an interesting one :)

Comment: @user1990577 I wish I had you here! lol, I think as much as I would want to do it, I lack the skill and this task would make my head spin. Thanks for your input, your help has help me understand this alot better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33721/discussion-between-user1990577-and-compcobalt)